# Chain Rule with 1/cos(x)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, chain-rule

In the statement of the attached snapshot it states:

$1/\cos(x)$ is made up of $1/g$ and $\cos()$:

$$f(g) = 1/g$$

How is $1/\cos(x)$ partially made up of $1/g$?

Where does $1/g$ come from?

[image]

Comment: if you set $\cos x=g$ the argument becomes clear

Comment: This is actually two nested functions.
If we have $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$ Then
$$\begin{align}1/\cos x&=f(g(x))\\ (1/ \cos x)'&= (f(g(x)))' \\ &=f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \\&=\left(\frac{-1}{g(x)^2}\right) \cdot (- \sin x) \\ &= \frac{\sin x}{ \cos ^2 x}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \cos x$. Then $\frac{1}{\cos x} = \frac{1}{g}$. Then
$$\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)' = \left(\frac{1}{g}\right)' = -\frac{1}{g^2}g' = -\frac{1}{\cos ^2x}(-\sin x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}$$